# Cannot insert NULL value in to FK column

Tags: mysql

Is there any other reason why I can't insert NULL value in the FK column ? I already tick the NULL checkbox, but unfortunately, it still does not enter the NULL value. It display this error:

> Fatal error: Uncaught mysqli_sql_exception: Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails

I know this error occur because the id must exist in the parent table, then only it can be insert in child table. But how if I want to insert the NULL value for the FK column? I already tick the NULL checkbox, but still the error occur.

```
$sql=$con->prepare("INSERT INTO note(notes, bookid) VALUES (?,?)");
$sql->bind_param('si', $notes, $bookid);
$sql->execute();
```

bookid is the FK. If I insert notes value it will insert a NULL value for bookid. But the NULL value did not enter the database

Comment: What did you set in "ON UPDATE" option?

Comment: Sorry sir. May I know what do you mean by "ON UPDATE" option ?

Comment: I cannot reproduce it: https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=1cb25deef0001f4199870be08a83e3ac

Comment: Hi sir. Thank you for your reply. But the value is not fix to be null. There is a time where the the value will be exist based on user selection

Comment: Andrea means we need to see the actual table definition and the SQL code that triggers the error. "tick the NULL checkbox" is as vague as it gets (MySQL Server doesn't have a GUI).

Comment: @ÁlvaroGonzález I think he is using GUI because he said "I ticked the NULL checkbox" ... and CLI doesn't have checkboxes actually

Comment: Sorry, I'm not sure of what "the value is not fix to be null" means. You can allow the column to be `NULL` and be able to insert `NULL` or make it mandatory and not be able to allow `NULL`. Other combinations don't make sense. Do you need help to gather table definition? What program are you using?

Comment: I am using phpmyadmin. Tick the NULL checkbox is I already checked the NULL box when creating the column. Sorry, forgot to mention that I am using php to insert the data in database. Will update the question above for you to see the SQL code

Comment: Maybe you forgot to add the ON UPDATE value in the relationship between tables